# when i try to count the number of likes instead it shows the number of ingredients used in the recipe

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

This is my mysql query

```
  SELECT r.RECIPE_ID as recipe_id,
    r.RECIPE_NAME as recipe_name,
    r.RECIPE_DESC as recipe_desc,
    r.RECIPE_DURATION duration,
    group_concat(i.ING_NAME separator ', ') as recipe_ingredients,
    rc.CUSINE_NAME as cusine,
    rt.RECIPE_TYPE_NAME as type,
    r.image ,
    count(lr.likecount)
    FROM RECIPE_LIST r 
    inner join likerecipes lr on r.recipe_id = lr.recipe_id
    inner JOIN RECIPE_INGLIST ri ON r.RECIPE_ID = ri.recipe_id 
    inner JOIN ING_LIST i ON ri.ING_ID = i.ING_id and r.RECIPE_ID = ri.recipe_id 
    inner JOIN RECIPE_CUSINE rc ON r.RECIPE_CUSINE_ID = rc.CUSINE_ID 
    inner JOIN RECIPE_TYPE rt ON r.RECIPE_TYPE_ID = rt.recipe_typeid 
    WHERE r.RECIPE_ID >= 1 
    GROUP BY r.RECIPE_NAME
```

The output table is displayed below
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7sW4.jpg)

But when i remove the ingredients field and all its joins and execute the same query

```
SELECT r.RECIPE_ID as recipe_id,
r.RECIPE_NAME as recipe_name,
r.RECIPE_DESC as recipe_desc,
r.RECIPE_DURATION duration,
rc.CUSINE_NAME as cusine,
rt.RECIPE_TYPE_NAME as type,
r.image ,
count(lr.likecount)
FROM RECIPE_LIST r 
inner join likerecipes lr on r.recipe_id = lr.recipe_id
inner JOIN RECIPE_CUSINE rc ON r.RECIPE_CUSINE_ID = rc.CUSINE_ID 
inner JOIN RECIPE_TYPE rt ON r.RECIPE_TYPE_ID = rt.recipe_typeid 
WHERE r.RECIPE_ID >= 1 
GROUP BY r.RECIPE_NAME
```

I get the desired result -> 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h19Ap.jpg)

Is there any way that i can display the right amount of likes along with the ingredients.
(PS. i know that the first query is showing no. of ingredients instead of likes because when i deduced one of the ingredients the like amount decreased. also the recipes displayed are displayed through a pivot table recipe_inglist joining recipe_list and ing_list table(if that had anything to do with it))

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate the likes before doing the rest of the joins:

```
FROM RECIPE_LIST r JOIN
     (SELECT lr.recipe_id, COUNT(*) as likes
      FROM likerecipes lr
      GROUP BY lr.recipe_id
     ) lr
     ON r.recipe_id = lr.recipe_id . . .
```

Comment: i did exactly what you told me to do and inserted the above queries, removed the pre-existing queries related to the likes but the output table does not even have the like column

Comment: You have to include `likes` in the `select`.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause .... Why do i get this error. when i tried to search it up it showed that it had something to do with the mysql version that i am using

Comment: @AtulStha . . . Your question is not about a view, it is about a query.  MySQL has additional restrictions on views.  If you have a question about views, then ask *another* question.